# Prevent adding duplicate data into JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, duplicates, jtable

How to prevent adding duplicate data into Jtable.

> This is my code.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/webservice/rest/bdetails/get");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        String json = "";
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
                        json += output;
        }

        conn.disconnect();
        java.lang.reflect.Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BDetails>>() {
                }.getType();

        List<BDetails> bList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);

        for( BDetails adr : bList) 
        {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pTable.getModel();
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
            row.add(detail.getUserName());
            row.add(detail.getFirstName());
            row.add(detail.getLastName());
            row.add(detail.getAddress();
            model.addRow( row );
        }
    } catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

When I run this method It add data to the table. When I run again It add same data to the table. And again it do the same. How can I fix that? Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance. Below I have added the BDetails Class.

> BDetails Class

```
public class BDetails 
{
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    public BDetails() {
    }

    public BDetails(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
```

Comment: Put the data into a `Set` first, then use this as you bases for your `TableModel`.  You will probably need a POJO with `equals` and `hashCode` support and make use of custom `TableModel` (based on `AbstractTableModel`, but you'll get more control over how things get done

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you say since I am new to programming. So how can I do that with this code?

Comment: Instead of using a `Vector` to store the information, make a "Plain Old Java Object" to store the data.  You can override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods (any decent IDE will guide you through how to make these work correctly) and then use a `Set` as the bases for your row information.  The `Set` will prevent duplicates (based on the `hashcode` of the objects)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried with `Object [ ]`. But it didn't work. So can you give me a code snippet. Since I am using `Web Services`.

Comment: What's `BDetails`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Class with `Getters and Setters`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169302/discussion-between-abraham-arnold-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: Yes, would you like to add it - because it looks like a POJO which might be of some use

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
        java.lang.reflect.Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BDetails>>() {
                }.getType();

        List<BDetails> bList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pTable.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);

        for( BDetails adr : bList) 
        {

            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
            row.add(detail.getUserName());
            row.add(detail.getFirstName());
            row.add(detail.getLastName());
            row.add(detail.getAddress();
            model.addRow( row );
        }
```

`model.setRowCount(0)` will clear all the rows before inserting data. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First, I took `BDetails` and used Netbeans to add the `equals` and `hashcode` methods.  This is important, as it provides away to assess if two instances of an object are the same

```
public class BDetails {

    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    public BDetails() {
    }

    public BDetails(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.username);
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.firstName);
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lastName);
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.address);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final BDetails other = (BDetails) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.username, other.username)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.address, other.address)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I then create a custom `TableModel` (I'm bias, but I don't have much love for `DefaultTableModel` and it makes the next step easier)

```
public class BDetailsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<BDetails> rows;
    private String[] columnNames = {"User name", "First name", "Last Name", "Address"};

    public BDetailsTableModel(List<BDetails> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        BDetails details = rows.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return details.getUsername();
            case 1:
                return details.getFirstName();
            case 2:
                return details.getLastName();
            case 3:
                return details.getAddress();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And finally...

```
List<BDetails> bList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
//for (BDetails adr : bList) {
//    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pTable.getModel();
//    Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
//    row.add(detail.getUserName());
//    row.add(detail.getFirstName());
//    row.add(detail.getLastName());
//    row.add(detail.getAddress();
//    model.addRow(row);
//}
Set<BDetails> unquie = new HashSet<>(bList);
List<BDetails> rows = new ArrayList<>(unquie);
BDetailsTableModel model = new BDetailsTableModel(rows);
pTable.setModel(model);
```

Okay, all this does is adds the `bList` to `Set`, this will remove all duplicates from the list for us (using the `hashcode` of the objects), add the results to a `ArrayList` (because it has a `get` method) and then supplies that to our `BDetailsTableModel`

Now, if you don't want to replace the `TableModel` each time, but instead, add the results it becomes a little more difficult, as you need to manage the possibility that the new set of data might contain duplicates of the old set.

You could add the following to `BDetailsTableModel`...

```
public void add(BDetails details) {
    int rowCount = getRowCount();
    if (rows.contains(details)) {
        return;
    }
    rows.add(details);
    fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount, rowCount);
}

public void addAll(List<BDetails> newRows) {
    Set<BDetails> rows = new HashSet<>(newRows);
    addAll(rows);
}

public void addAll(Set<BDetails> newRows) {
    Set<BDetails> allRows = new HashSet<>(rows);
    allRows.addAll(newRows);

    rows = new ArrayList<>(allRows);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

and instead of creating a new instance of `BDetailsTableModel`, simply use the existing instance (from `pTable`) and use the above functionality to add new rows

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for your answer.